# Can I using increment for properties in response?

Tags: mocking, wiremock

Can I using increment for properties in response?
For example, i want, that my property in response wasn't hardcode, but using increment and with every creating number increased +1:

```
{ 
  "request": {
    "method": "POST",
    "url": "/bla"
  },

  "response": {
    "status": 200,
    "bla_id": "i+1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Does the content of `i` come from the original request, or should that integer be maintained by the WireMock server?

Comment: thanks, i understand your question. Noup 'I' doen't come from request. I found solution, i use Randomize, I have enough of this